# How can I export several columns from MySQL to text file

Tags: mysql

I know how to export multiple columns to a csv file. using:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

When I open the file using excel, everything is fine, each record is in a line. But, when I open it using notepad, I find all records are printed next to each other without line separator. How can I make the output of the query to be printed as one record per line and each column separated by comma ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\n` is a line break under linux, but windows uses `\r\n`

Accordingly, this code does what you want

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Many other tools like Excel, Notepad++ or WordPad can read file both with `\n` and `\r\n`, so they are not affected by this change and display the file correctly both with your original code and this modification.

Answer (score 0):

'\n' is used as Line separator in Unix/Linux, Line separator for Windows should be '\r\n'.