# Export mysql rows into different files

Tags: mysql, sql, file, export

I have a mySQL table which contains html code and some other information.

One example like this:

```
SELECT id, lang, html 
FROM mytable t
WHERE type = 10
```

give the result:

```
id     lang     html
-------------------------------------------------------
20     fr       '<html> ... html code here </html>'
21     de       '<html> ... html code here </html>'
22     it       '<html> ... html code here </html>'
23     en       '<html> ... html code here </html>'
```

and my idea is to export the html code into one file per lines like

- `20_fr.html` will contains the html columns for id 20
- `21_de.html` will contains the html columns for id 21
- etc...

Is it possible to do so in SQL language only like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12538281/628006) for exporting all rows into one file.

I know I can do it with Java or any other language but I am interested only by a SQL (a stored procedure could be ok).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the SELECT statement with the INTO and OUTFILE clauses.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

```
SELECT html
FROM mytable
WHERE lang = 'fr'
INTO OUTFILE 'frdata.txt'
```

The following SQL query might be used to generate one file output statement per row in the table.  Note the use of the CONCAT function to build a new SQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE command per row.

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'SELECT html from mytable where lang=''', lang, '''', ' INTO OUTFILE ''', CAST(id AS CHAR), '_', lang, '.html'';')

FROM mytable

ORDER BY id;
```

This will yield the the statements:

```
SELECT html from mytable where lang='fr' INTO OUTFILE '20_fr.html';

SELECT html from mytable where lang='de' INTO OUTFILE '21_de.html';

SELECT html from mytable where lang='it' INTO OUTFILE '22_it.html';

...
```

Comment: The OP asked how to export every line in a different file, this will export everything in the same one

Comment: The WHERE clause will allow this requirement to be met.  In the example above only the 'fr' row will be selected and inserted into the output file.

Comment: I've amended my response to include a SQL statement to generate multiple OUTFILE commands.

Comment: But where the files are going to be saved? I tried this but cannot find it on the disk.

Comment: @ruffp: To make the files easy to find I recommend using the full path in the OUTFILE clause.  
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484471/cant-find-the-file-created-by-outfile-in-mysql

Comment: Yes but the mysqld process can only write into /tmp. Anyway by following your link I found the files under /var/lib... after I can always make a system command (I am under linux) to move the sql and html file in the right folder.

Comment: Another funny thing is: writing e.g to `/home/myuser/dump.sql` is not allowed but from a sql script containing the system command I can execute: `system mkdir /home/myuser/result` and `system mv /var/lib/mysql/schema/dump.sql /home/myuser/result`

Comment: @ruffp: You might consider asking a question on the DBA stackexchange site to address the question of where the MySQL server can write files and the permissions/configuration needed to support writing files to a different location.  If my answer is helpful please mark it as accepted.

Comment: For information, I asked [that question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/64809/16243) in the [DBA StackExchange Site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) but no real answer yet for the real reasons.